# Inviting new users (after private beta)

Tags: discussion

There was a meta question about emailing invites here:
[Inviting new users](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/inviting-new-users), but it was about the private beta.

I didn't know about the private beta and only joined the QCSE more than a month after the public beta started.

I see this [Could the "private" be changed to "public" on the invitation form?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/could-the-private-be-changed-to-public-on-the-invitation-form), but don't know where to get that invitation link.

Is there a link we can use to invite new people or do we just tell them by word of mouth?

Is there any reward for inviting people?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the "**Invite Fellow Experts**" option (it's actually [a bug](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/227/26), but you may use it as long as they don't fix it). You will find it [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions). Scroll down a bit. It should be on the right side of your screen if you're using "Desktop mode" for browsing. Just type in their email id and add a custom message (optional) and click on "send invite". Stack Exchange will send them a mail with a link to this site's main page (on your behalf i.e. your user id/name will be visible on the mail). The only downside is that it still shows "private" instead of "public".

Just in case you're curious, here's how a custom mail from Stack Exchange looks (when using the Invite Fellow Experts option):

[image]

The other options are, of course, *directly* inviting people you know, by providing them the link: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/ via mail, social media or word-of-mouth.

I'm not aware of any reward(s) associated with inviting people (in the public beta phase) to the site (even they sign up and/or are someone famous in the field). Anyhow, if you do want such badges to be introduced, better raise the issue on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), as Stack Exchange is unlikely to introduce such badges for a single site only. However, do keep in mind that there are some *inherent* problems with "badges for being able to successfully persuade *famous* people to join the site". As I [mentioned earlier](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/26), it is pretty much impossible to verify a person's real identity, online (at least without making some major changes to the Stack Exchange framework).